# React native alert Freezes App when sent to background and came back to foreground

Tags: react-native

i am facing issue with alert when alert shown and i pushed my app to background and after some time when i came to foreground it throws me this error and freezes the app on IOS.

Thread 1: “Application tried to present modally a view controller <UIViewController: 0x1140b8cb0> that is already being presented by <UIViewController: 0x114018200>.”

react-native : 0.64.2
react-native-reanimated: ^1.8.0

Comment: How do you call an alert?

Comment: Alert.alert(
          languages.add_caregiver_title + "?",
          languages.add_caregiver_message,
          [
            {
              text: languages.skip,
              onPress: this.cancelTutorial
            },
            {
              text: languages.add_caregiver_btn_1,
              onPress: this.goToCareTeam
            }
          ],
          {cancelable: false}
        );

this is how i call an alert when component gets focussed